# Persist last style in AnimationBuilder

Tags: angular, animation, angular-animations

I am using `AnimationBuilder` inside a directive and I need to persist some styles after animation. My current code is:

```js
const animationPlayer: AnimationPlayer = this.animationBuilder.build([
    style({ scale: 1 }),
    animate('250ms ease-out', style({ scale: 1.25 }))
]).create(this.elementRef.nativeElement);

animationPlayer.play();
```

The problem is, the final style `scale: 1.25` is not persisted. I thought of adding the states but I can't find how to switch states in `AnimationBuilder`